# 1995 Buick LeSabre Start Up Issues

Tags: electrical, starting, buick, lesabre

I have a 1995 Buick LeSabre that is having some issues starting. For brief background, I live in MN so its gets quite cold. So cold that when it was -8 a week ago my battery was killed and needed to be replaced. Everything has been running fine since. That being said I just returned from a 4 day vacation and my car will not start. The temperature never was below 18 degrees while I was gone so I am unsure if the cold weather draining the battery is to blame this time.

The symptoms are as follows:

- Lights and radio turn on
- Car won't turn
- No clicking sound
- Security light does not stay on

I am at a bit of a loss because when its been a battery issue there has always been accompanying clicking and its not completely draining since the lights come on. If it was a security issues, VATS in this instance, the security light should stay on.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I can look into?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First, when you turn the key to start the engine, do all the lights dim or go off? Check the battery connections to ensure they are tight. Also, have you check the shifter to ensure it is solidly in **`P`** to engage the safety switch? Lastly, have the battery tested. Just because it is new, doesn't mean it can not be defective. Update your question with these additional details and we'll go from there.

Comment: @CharlieRB  I did not take note of the whether the lights dimmed or not.  I will check the parking to make sure it is solidly engaged as well as getting the battery tested.  Thanks for these - I'll be checking in a couple hours when I get back from work.  Appreciate your answer.

Comment: It isn't really an answer because I don't know what is wrong. The comment was really trying to get more information so I might attempt an answer. Regardless, hope you are able to resolve this unfortunate situation.